# I want to kill a player if he went higher then 24 blocks

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I want to make a Spigot Plugin that kills a Player if he is over 24 Blocks.
I already made a code but it doesn't work
Here is the full code, I don't need to register a new class because I wrote the event in the main class

```
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class MainFFA extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("_____________START_____________");
    getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("_____________START_____________");
    getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("_____________START_____________");
    getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("_____________START_____________");
    super.onEnable();
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage("_________STOP_________-");
    super.onDisable();
}
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDead(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    if(p.getLocation().getBlockY() > 80) {
        p.setHealth(0);
    }
    else {
        p.sendMessage("Wenn du das siehst dann bist du unter 80 blöcken hoch");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Do you get any errors? Did you remember to annotate this with `@EventHandler`, and register this listener in your main class?

Comment: Oh.. hahaha forgot the event handler. Lets see if it works thabk you, else i tell u

Comment: @Kerooker  still not working

Comment: We need to see more code to pinpoint your issue. Please update your question with pieces from your `OnEnable` and a full example on how you're handling the event.

Comment: @Kerooker ok did it

Comment: The PlayerMoveEvent runs very quickly, sending a player a message in the event is going to spam them a lot. If you want to send them a message, make a variable to check whether you have already sent the message so you don't spam the user.

Comment: @Sean I believe that this isn't an issue, as the player will be killed (thus not moving anymore) at the first instant they're above 80

Comment: I understand it's not the issue, just they are making an else meaning they are below Y at 80, which will spam the player. Simply a heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, you must remember to **register your listeners**, or else bukkit will never see them.

```
public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}
```

Add that line to the `onEnable` method, and you should be fine

Comment: @Leopa if this solves your issue, remember to mark it as the right answer, to help future users