# I want to teleport Players if he respawns, but its not working, the player don't get teleported

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

So I made a plugin that registers events after doing /pvpeventon and unregisters all after doing /pvpeventoff.
It is a PVPeventplugin.
I want to teleport Players after they respawn, but its not working. they don't get teleported. btw: I don't code Spigot a long time. here is my code:

```
package me.leopa.R1.FFA;




import org.bukkit.Location;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerRespawnEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;




public class MainFFA extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    System.out.println("[INFO Leopa] Start");
    super.onEnable();
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
System.out.println("[INFO Leopa] Stop");
super.onDisable();
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {


    if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("PVPEVENTon")) {
        if(sender instanceof Player) {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

        }
    }



    if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("PVPEVENToff")) {
        HandlerList.unregisterAll();
    }
    return true;


    }
@EventHandler
public void onRespawnPVPEVENT(PlayerRespawnEvent pvpevent) {
    Player p = pvpevent.getPlayer();
    double x = 22;
    double y = 82;
    double z = 22;
    Location loc = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), x, y, z);
    p.teleport(loc);


}
@EventHandler
public void sed(PlayerDeathEvent totevent) {
    Player p1 = totevent.getEntity();
    p1.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[PvP Event] " + ChatColor.AQUA + "Du Bist Gestorben und somit raus");
}


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to kill a player if he went higher then 24 blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266854/i-want-to-kill-a-player-if-he-went-higher-then-24-blocks)

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate because the error faced in the linked question is the same here. The asker forgot to register the events at `onEnable()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PlayerRespawnEvent` has a method, `setRespawnLocation()`, that allows you to change where the player will respawn.  Your handler for `PlayerRespawnEvent` should look something like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onRespawnPVPEVENT(PlayerRespawnEvent pvpevent) {
    Player p = pvpevent.getPlayer();
    double x = 22;
    double y = 82;
    double z = 22;
    Location loc = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), x, y, z);
    pvpevent.setRespawnLocation(loc);
}
```